# Scrolling vs. Tapping on mobile

Tags: touch-screen, scrolling, ipad, tablet, click

I'm designing a product detail page for tablet (mainly iPad). Given the limitation of screen size (although the new iPad is bigger now), there are content that's cutoff at the bottom. The requirement is to see them right off the bet but it doesn't make sense to show them on top. We tried another version to show the two sections at the bottom in two tabs but the concern is that people have to tap to see the other section. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely clear as to what your question is. Are you asking if tabs are appropriate? FYI, your layout 'feels' rather desktop centric rather than touch-centric. I'd suggest avoiding scrolling sections and make  all your touchable spots much bigger.

Comment: Yes I was asking if tabs or scrolling will work better for the "You May Also Like" and "Customers Also Bought" sections. Sorry the wireframe looks desktop centric. The actual visual design has bigger touch targets.

Comment: In general, people prefer scrolling--*especially* on touch devices, where it's very easy to do.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a tap would require extra efforts from the user. Why make user to take such steps.
Scrolling is synonymous to exploring without causing the pain.

Plus when I look at other Ecommerce apps, scroll is used almost everywhere. Have a look at some of these Images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your design should be able to better capture the features of touch devices.

You can use a card sorting method for the page that would showcase each product tile.

Look at other shopping apps out there. There are lots of apps that keep breaking down the view in such a manner that you're constantly drilling down for more product detail.

I would suggest having all your information inline and expand open further information on the page.

Biggest thing is to see what's been done already. There are lots of good examples that don't feel like a rehash of a desktop site.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments to your question: Go with scroll!

But never forget: Most people don't like to read a lot. So, if you can, try to keep texts short and easy to read too.